# Error using vim.lsp.buf.definition() in any C# classes

Tags: neovim, lsp

The setup I have works fine for tsserver but not the csharp_ls

```
local servers =  { 'tsserver', 'csharp_ls' }

local on_attach  = function(client, bufnr)
   vim.keymap.set('n', 'gd', ":vsplit | wincmd w | lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<cr>", {buffer=0})
end

local lsp_flags = {
  debounce_text_changes = 150,
}

for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
  nvim_lsp[lsp].setup{
    on_attach = on_attach,
    flags = lsp_flags
  }
end
```

Log confirms that the project is loading and it is getting initialized.

> LSP[csharp_ls][Log] csharp-ls: OK, 1 project files loaded

> LSP[csharp_ls][Log] csharp-ls: "initialized" notification received from client

But then I get the following error when trying to navigate to a definition.

> Error executing vim.schedule lua callback: ...s\neovim\current\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/lsp/util.lua:1735: index out of range
> stack traceback:
> [C]: in function '_str_byteindex_enc'
> ...s\neovim\current\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/lsp/util.lua:1735: in function 'locations_to_items'
> ...ovim\current\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/lsp/handlers.lua:352: in function 'handler'
> ...p\apps\neovim\current\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/lsp.lua:1390: in function 'cb'
> vim/_editor.lua:262: in function <vim/_editor.lua:261>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used LspInfo to determine that csharp_ls wasn't finding my solution properly. It found the project, but I was trying to navigate to a definition located in a different project in the same solution. I wasn't able to figure out how to configure csharp_ls to find the solution so I downloaded omnisharp via Mason and it worked out of the box.